# Solving exponential decay problem with solve_ivp - Python

Tags: python, ode

I am testing my exponential decay class. I want to check that when the initial value is 0, the output will also be zero. However, when I print value of exp. decay with solve method I get the value 1.0.
This is my code:

```
def test_initial_condition():
"""Tests if the array consists of zeros when initial cond. is 0"""
    a = 0.4
    u0 = 0
    exp_decay = ExponentialDecay(a)
    t, u = exp_decay.solve(u0, 5, 10)
    print(u[0])
    assert u[0] == 0
```

Error message:
E       assert 1.0 == 0
E         -1.0
E         +0

test_exp_decay.py:38: AssertionError

Comment: This looks all unproblematic, the error has to be in the details of your class. One guess would be that somewhere you have transferred wrongly the initial value as a constant `1.0` or as `exp(u0)`.

Comment: yes, you were correct. Changed the int. value inside my class, and now it works. Thnks! :)